# width DIV in TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML:

```
<table class="tab">
    <tr><td>aa</td><td>aa</td><td>aa</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><div class="in">bbb</div></td></tr>
</table>

<table class="tab">
    <tr><td>aa</td><td>aa</td><td>aa</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><div class="in">bbbbb</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
.tab td {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.in {
    background-color: green
}
```

How can I set that green background to have the same width as text in this DIV, not for all TD?

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/xE4gS/

Comment: +1 They tried something. We have code.  They (or Roy perhaps) added a jsfiddle.  This seems pretty legit attempt to me for a newbie, not just 'write my code'.

Comment: All the quick answerers below are ok with it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want the green background to be the same width as the text in the `div`?

If so, change the `div` to a `span`. This is because `div` is a block-level element, and means that only one element can appear on one line, so it will automatically fill all horizontal space available. An `inline` element, such as a `span` allows for multiple elements to be placed on one line.

Alternatively, you can make the `div` inline, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xE4gS/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a span rather than a div? Assuming that's what you wanted.

```
<table class="tab">
    <tr><td>aa</td><td>aa</td><td>aa</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><div><span class="in">bbb</span></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/xE4gS/2/

Comment: @PeterShootring You can do it with a div by floating, but then you need to use other hacks to get rid of the float. Span is probably the best option. You could use a jQuery script to automatically add the spans. Rorys answer seems best.

Answer (score 2):

Add text into span, not in div

```
<span class="in">xbbbb</span>


span.in {
 background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color the background in green with the same width as the text inside the div you can change the div to a span.

From w3School:
The  tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
The  tag provides no visual change by itself.
The  tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.
When the text is hooked in a span element you can add styles to the content, or manipulate the content with for example JavaScript.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp